# Protractor tests failing randomly - screenshot error : WebDriverError: chrome not reachable

Tags: webdriver, protractor, google-chrome-headless

I am running protractor tests on chrome headless in Ubuntu 16.04. The tests were running properly for more than 3 months but then suddenly the tests started failing with the below error-

[npm run e2e console - Chrome not reachable error from the very beginning of the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Un8g.png)

[Chrome not reachable error after successfully running few tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auhzt.png)

```
Protractor configuration - 
    // Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
    // 


  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js

/*global jasmine */

var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  suites: {
    V3_Sanity: [
      './e2e/Flows/Sanity/**/analytics_dashboard.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/Sanity/**/executive_dashboard.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/Sanity/**/my_views.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/Sanity/**/question_analysis.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/Sanity/**/responses.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/Sanity/**/login_page.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    V3_e2e: [
      './e2e/Flows/E2E/**/flow1.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/E2E/**/flow2.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/E2E/**/flow3.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/E2E/**/flow4.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/E2E/**/flow5.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/E2E/**/flow6.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    QB_Sanity: [
      './e2e/Flows/QB Sanity/**/question_config.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/QB Sanity/**/right_panel.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/QB Sanity/**/question_types.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    CT_Sanity: [
      './e2e/Flows/Contingency Table Sanity/**/CT_load_test.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    Response_Filter: [
      './e2e/Flows/ResponsesFilter/responses_filter.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    DropOff: [
      './e2e/Flows/Response DropOff/response_drop_off.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    Trend_Notification: [
      './e2e/Flows/Trend Based Notification/trend_sanity.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    Response_Filter: [
      './e2e/Flows/ResponsesFilter/responses_filter_analytics.e2e-spec.ts',
      './e2e/Flows/ResponsesFilter/responses_filter_responses.e2e-spec.ts'
    ]
  },
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1440x900", "--no-sandbox"]
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    print: function () { }
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,

  beforeLaunch: function () {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e'
    });
  },

  onPrepare: function () {
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    require('ts-node').register({ project: 'e2e' });
    var fs = require('fs-extra');

    fs.emptyDir('./e2e/target/screenshots/', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
      specDone: function (result) {
        if (result.status == 'failed') {
          browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
            var browserName = caps.get('browserName');

            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
              console.log("taken")
              var stream = fs.createWriteStream('e2e/target/screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName + '.png');
              stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
              stream.end();
            }, (err) => {
              console.log("screenshot error : " + err)
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });

    // jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
      consolidateAll: true,
      savePath: './e2e/target/screenshots',
      filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
    }));
  },

  afterLaunch: function (exitCode) {
  },

  //HTMLReport called once tests are finished
  onComplete: function () {

    //save browser logs
    browser.manage().logs()
      .get('browser').then(function (browserLog) {
        console.log('log :' +
          require('util').inspect(browserLog));
      });

    var browserName, browserVersion;
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
      browserName = caps.get('browserName');
      browserVersion = caps.get('version');

      var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter');

      testConfig = {
        reportTitle: 'Test Execution Report',
        outputPath: 'e2e/target/screenshots',
        screenshotPath: '.',
        testBrowser: browserName,
        browserVersion: browserVersion,
        modifiedSuiteName: false,
        screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true
      };
      new HTMLReport().from('e2e/target/screenshots/xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
    });
  }
};
```

By randomly I mean, sometimes the whole test runs successfully but sometimes it fails at the very beginning of the test or after running a few test suites, with the error message "screenshot error : WebDriverError: chrome not reachable".

I am facing this issue in my cloud ubuntu 16.04 server. Which was running properly until recently but suddenly it has started failing.

Another point to be noted is, it runs successfully for less number of test suits.Also these tests are running properly in my local Ubuntu 16.04 machine and have never got this issue while running in headless.

I also tried reinstalling chrome, but it didn't help.

I checked memory usage also, but will running the tests it has sufficient memory available.

I referred other stackoverflow issues but they are all related to protractor configuration issues. Which seems to fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu and found that I had to do two things:

1) Include a path to your ChromeDriver in PATH and the webdriver env varible:

```
export webdriver.chrome.driver="/usr/bin/chromedriver"
export PATH=$webdriver.chrome.driver:$PATH
```

2) Add the path to the Chrome browser binary (the actual browser, not driver) file in ChromeOptions. This is needed when running headless.

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  "chromeOptions": {
    binary: '/path/to/chrome/binary',
    args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1440x900", "--no-sandbox"]
  }   
}
```

On my Ubuntu, the binary path is /usr/bin/google-chrome (after intalling it through a .deb package)

See if this helps you.

Comment: I tried this. It run successfully for sometime. But I'm getting the same  issue again.

Comment: After updating nodejs and npm it is working fine now.

Comment: That is great. Glad to hear.